# how send sqlite database to server in android

Tags: android

I just want to send my database file from the application to send it to the server. The database is for the same application, so I would think that it is doable, I just have no idea how to try it

Comment: In server how would you like store this database, As a file or you need to retrieve data from SQLite database and store it to some other database for ex SQL server like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending SQLite db to web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114725/sending-sqlite-db-to-web-service)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your database is a file and you can get the database file,default by

```
Context ctx = this; // for Activity, or Service. Otherwise simply get the context.
String dbname = "mydb.db";//your db name
Path dbpath = ctx.getDatabasePath(dbname);
```

then you can copy this file then send it to your server using http methods as normal.

But i suggest you send the content of this database not database file,because it will have some extra contents need to transfer,but these maybe not essential.

Comment: Since you get the db file,just **google send file to your server** you will get an answer,if  you use some http framework like Volley,XUtils,they provide such method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String DB_PATH;
DB_PATH = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17 ? getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/" : "/data/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/";


File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.DB_NAME));
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
    Log.d(TAG,"databse is exists "+dbFile.exists());
```

> > Send dbFile to server across network using http connection class

Answer (score -1):

As discussion, sqlite databse is nothing but a single file, you can share this file but as you said this sqlite file belongs to the same application which is sending the file to server. see in this scenario the db-file is in use so i think you will face difficulty in concurrent reading of this file, may be you will not get updated file if current changes are going on.
Otherwise you can directly send file via web service or upload it on ftp of server or any other convenient way.

Comment: dear help me how can i do in better way please me